# Intent get photo from gallery

Tags: android, image, android-intent, uri, android-external-storage

I'm a newbie to android, I'm having a few small questions when working with Intent to get images from the gallery, the possible ways to get the images I can use like:
Type 1:

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(getIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
```

it return  uri `content://media/external/images/media/...`

Type 2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY);
```

it return  uri `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image...`

please help me explain the meaning of the above 2 types of uri and what should be used in what cases, i have searched but did not get the results i wanted, any help is worth it Best regards. Thanks everyone

Comment: Just use the obtained uries or content schemes. They are from different content providers as you can see. But that is pretty irrelevant as how to use them is the same.

Comment: Try ACTION_,OPEN_DOCUMENT too and dont call it Type 3.